# Multiple selections in metabox

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to make the user the ability to chose several posts that related to the post that his about the publish, so that post will shown at the bottom of the post itself.
So I created a metabox with multiple selctions.
Now I have two problems:
1)Save his chooses as array of options. I've manage to do it only with this code:

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, 'related-posts', array_map( 'strip_tags', $_POST['related-posts']) );
```

The thing is that it makes array-of-array:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=8)
      0 => string '38262' (length=5)
      1 => string '38257' (length=5)
      2 => string '38247' (length=5)
      3 => string '38217' (length=5)
      4 => string '38228' (length=5)
      5 => string '38229' (length=5)
      6 => string '38211' (length=5)
      7 => string '38198' (length=5)
```

Is this the right way of doing it? there's no better solution to make it only one-dimensional array? (I don't want to use implode method).

2)When the choises were saved, they need to be highlighted, so I've tried this:

```
$array_posts = get_posts($args); ?>
<form action="" method="post" name="related-post-form"> 
    <select name='related-posts[]' multiple='multiple' size='30'>
        <?php foreach($array_posts as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" <?php if ($_POST['related-posts'] == $post->ID ) echo ' selected'; ?>><?php the_title(); ?></option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciate.. Thanks!

Comment: `$_POST['related-posts']` would be an array. Try https://php.net/in_array

Comment: Yeah and also remove the "[]" from the name of the field ;) Then the array-array-problem should be gone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..can you be more specific please?

Comment: About what exactly? The "in_array" part is explained on php.net.
The other thing comes down to changing this `<select name='related-posts[]' multiple='multiple' size='30'>` to this `<select name='related-posts' multiple='multiple' size='30'>`. The value of a multiple select is always interpreted as an array, because it has more thant one value. If you put the brackets behind the name, php thinks that he acutally gets more than only one set of data from the name `related_posts` and puts every value it finds into the array for that name.